# How to save the data in the GUI to the text file (java)

Tags: java, user-interface, error-handling, save, text-files

I tried to save the data (that the user will enter in the TextField) to the textfile. However it will only says error.

By the way this is my code.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    String name = jTextField1.getText();
    String age = jTextField2.getText();
    String sex = jTextField3.getText();
    String status = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String address = jTextField4.getText();
    String contactNum = jTextField5.getText();
    String emailAdd = jTextField6.getText();
    String userName = jTextField7.getText();
    String password = jTextField8.getText();
    
    try
    {
        FileWriter Writer = new FileWriter("admin.txt");
        Writer.write("Name: " + name + " Age: " + age + " Sex: " + 
                sex + " Status: " + status + " Address: " + address +
                " Contact # :  " + contactNum + " Email Add.: " + emailAdd +
                " Username: " + userName + " Password: " + password);
        Writer.write(System.getProperty("line.seperator"));
        Writer.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Admin account was created successfully");
        setVisible(false);
        new frontpage().setVisible(false);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it yourself? Try printing the exception.

Comment: *JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error!");* - how does always displaying "error" provide any useful information? The point of catching an exception is to display the Exception so you know what the problem is. Also, variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn by example. All textbooks and tutorial will follow Java naming conventions. Most of your names are correct, but not all. Be consistent!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that your FileWriter declaration is incorrect. Never set variable names same as the target class name. Always aim to use lower case letters for variables. Therefore:

```
FileWriter Writer = new FileWriter("admin.txt");
```

should be written like this:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("admin.txt");
```

Afterwards, you call methods like this:

```
writer.write(someString);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

**These two are the most important:**

```
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

And next time when you ask a question, please provide the Exception message, it will help when answering the question.